# Google Cloud Platform Console - Each visit to Stackdriver/Logging page results in an error being reported

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-console

I came across an odd behaviour of Google Cloud Platform Console. It seems that each visit to "Stackdriver" -> "Logging" produces an error. Unfortunately, this error is only manifested by incrementing the total number of errors shown in "IAM & Admin" -> "All projects" and no additional information regarding the nature of the error is available.

The "Logging" page works perfectly fain with absolutely no error reports. Both the App Engine and API Manager dashboards report no errors happening.

Would anyone be so kind as to check if this behaviour affects their projects as well? To reproduce this behavior, you can do the following (it takes less than 10 seconds):

1. Go to "IAM & Admin" -> "All projects"
2. Look at the "Error" column of the overview table
3. Then go to "Stackdriver" -> "Logging"
4. Then go back to "IAM & Admin" -> "All projects"
5. The number of errors will now be increased by one

I am using Java and the application is deployed in EU-West. The billing is not yet enabled.

My appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

My logging.properties:

```
.level = WARNING
```

Comment: I can't repro, in my case that number of errors doesn't increase. It matches the total of all the errors displayed at the bottom of the "App Engine" -> "Dashboard" page for that project. Python/US.